# Knockout JSON data reloading issue with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I've loaded an ASP.NET MVC viewModel into KnockoutJS using ko.mapping.fromJS(Model).

My viewModel looks something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<FunkyThing>funkyThings;
public FunkyThing selectedFunkyThing;
```

Each FunkyThing has a string property funkyThingName.
The mapping worked fine and I can see all the funky things in the table with their names.

I want to add a quick refresh button.  So I've created a simple button and then data bound the buttons click to a knockout function refresh which looks something like this:

```
   model.refresh= function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action(MVC.FunkyThings.RefreshJSON())';
            $.getJSON(url, function (returnedData) {                
                ko.mapping.fromJS(returnedData, {}, model.funkyThings);
            });
```

The refresh function is succesfully called which in turn calls the RefreshJSON method on the server.  The server passes back JSON data - an updated array of funkyThings, which I can see within chrome when I hover over returnedData in chrome's debugger.

However unfortunately after the mapping function has been called the bindings break:

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: funkyThingName is not defined;
Bindings value: text: funkyThingName

And I'm not sure why...?

Comment: Can you include the code from the function that has the original get, as opposed to the refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `model.funkyThings` an observable? If it is, then you can try passing it into the mapping method as a function:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(returnedData, {}, model.funkyThings());
```

Failing that, are you sure that the structure of the JSON returned by the refresh method is correct?

Ah, if you're getting a JSON string back, so you need to call the fromJSON method of the mapping plugin:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(returnedData, {}, model.funkyThings);
```

You might need the parenthesis on funkyThings here too, but try it without first.

Comment: Thanks.  Using the parenthesis got rid of the exception.  However no changes seem to be occurring.

I've tried model.funkyThings.valueHasMutated(); however the list just stays the same

Comment: Did you try the fromJSON method too?

Comment: I tried both.  I'm fairly certain it's the fromJS one I want.  I'm using on the C# side:
public JsonResult RefreshJSON()
{
....
//
refreshy stuff
//
return Json(viewModel.funkyThings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Everywhere else I've needed to use fromJS

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON you're getting back?

Comment: Your idea helped me sus it Paul.  The original knockout model was created using the method here:
http://www.aaron-powell.com/javascript/creating-vms-from-server

This used camel case to produce the JSON.
My method was using the MVC Json class and it wasn't producing camelcase.

After changing the Server RefreshJSON to return camelcased JSON  the issue was resolved.  Thanks for your pointers!

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the returned object is in the correct format and also the binding is well done you
just need to do:

```
    model.FunkyThings(returnedData).
```

Comment: Considering that: _Funky things is an observable array_ and the returned object is a collection of funky thing objects